# New to REGEX Extract In Big Query, REGEX formatting issue

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

I am trying to extract variable urls that always occur after `referrer\",\"Value\":\"` and end with `\",\"IgnoreForCache\"`

what is in between is always a url but could be of various length or characters. For example: `https://www.123abc.com or https://www.abc123.com/456def/xyz/`

The full array looks like:

a bunch of random values (including other urls)

```
referrer\",\"Value\":\"https://abc123xyz.net/\",\"IgnoreForCache
```

a bunch of random values (including other urls)

and I only want the referrer url to be returned.

My current query is the following:
 `SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(ColumnA,r'\breferrer\b.....\bValue\b.....') FROM database`

Which returns:

`referrer\",\"Value\":\"`

which gets me closer, But I can't figure out the just extracting the url I want and how to deal with variable lengths and characters.

Thank you!

Comment: This looks like JSON, so you should use the [JSON Functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions) to process it rather than regexp.

Comment: It does look like JSON but does not appear to be stored as JSON, for instance simple array statements are failing, which tells me this isn't being stored as an array

Comment: The escaped quotes look like it's doubly-encoded JSON.

Comment: Ahh maybe that is why its not working, so if it is doubly-encoded any advice for extracting the data?

Comment: Use nested `JSON_PARSE()` calls.